# Raylib for C++ DrawText() adds 0s to floats

Tags: c++, floating-point, raylib

In my program I have a float

```
float integrity = 5.6;
```

and I want to draw it on the screen.
To do this, I use the DrawText function:

```
DrawText(TextFormat("%f",integrity), 300, 160, 30, WHITE);
```

But I get a bunch of zeros at the end that make everything look ugly.

What I expect: 5.6
The result:    5.600000

Comment: Remember that when you type: `float integrity = 5.6;` your computer will not store exactly `5.6` instead it stores `5.599999904632568359375` it is incapable to store exactly 5.6 as a float because of how floating point numbers are implemented. See here:   [https://h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter](https://h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter)

Answer (score 0):

I can use "%.2f" in the DrawText() Function to round to the nearest 2 decimal points, that should pretty it up.